# Stencil picking test always returns 0

Tags: opengl, glreadpixels

I'm trying to implement a simple picking method in my OpenGL program. 
First, I clear the stencil with

```
glClearStencil(0);
```

and at the start of my displayCallback function, I call

```
GLbitfield mask = GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT;

glClear(mask);
```

then I draw all object in scene, except 4 object, which I want to be selectable (the rest is non interactive). When I draw these 4 object, I first enable and set Stencil

```
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
```

and then draw

```
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, i + 1, -1);
drawItem( ... );
```

where i is the index of an item, and then call

```
glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
```

When I try to pick an item when user clicks left mosue button, I use this in mouseCallback function

```
if ((buttonPressed == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) && (buttonState == GLUT_DOWN)) {

    unsigned char column = 0;

    glReadPixels(mouseX, 
                (WINDOW_WIDTH - mouseY + 1), 
                1, 
                1, 
                GL_STENCIL_INDEX, 
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                &column);

    if (column == 0) {      
        printf("Clicked at %d %d, No column clicked on\n", mouseX, mouseY);
    }
    else {              
        printf("Clicked on column with ID: %d\n", (int)column);
    }
}
```

But no matter where I click, I never select any column. I even added the mouseX and mouseY to check if I'm not clicking on the same pixel, but I found out that this part works ok.

Does anyone see any problem with this code? Thanks a lot-

Comment: Did you remember to allocate a stencil buffer, by using the `GLUT_STENCIL` bit in your call to `glutInitDisplayMode`?

Comment: I did, but thanks for pointing that out. I'm currently using glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL);

Comment: It would be great if you could boil this down into a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Basically, just draw one simple thing at a known location with stenciling enabled, then read the stencil back. It should be the exact stencil value that you wrote.

Comment: One of the problems is that this program is very extensive by now. It has something around 3000 lines of code and doing that is very complicated. I tried using this approach on another project, which worked perfectly.
Anyway, I just tried using a stencil on every object I draw, even a skybox, so everything should now return a value != 0, yet everyting still returns 0. It seems that I somehow cleared my stencil, but I'm not sure how or where that happened

Comment: very well, my stencil doesnt seem to be cleared, it's just that glReadPixels doesnt do anything with column variable without returning any error. Now just to figure out why

Comment: Probably not your only problem based on the symptoms, but subtracting `mouseY` from `WINDOW_WIDTH` looks fishy. Unless `WINDOW_WIDTH` is in fact the height of the window.

Comment: oh my god that was it! That really actually fixed the issue. It seems that the Y part was negative on the whole screen since I was using 2:1 aspect ratio. That also explains why this function worked on the other program I tried it on, because it has 1:1 aspect ratio. The thing is however, why did glReadPixels not throw any error? But anyway, thanks a lot sir!

Comment: I have rolled back your edit. Please post your solution as an answer.